# Jquery ui style not displaying when load content on ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have 2 pages: index.php and form1.php.
In my index.php I have a button which has function to load content of form1.php on div:

```
$("#btnLoadContent").button().click(function(){
$("#divcontent").empty().load("form1.php")});
```

On form1.php y have a form and a button named btnSend.
On index i'm using this:

```
$("#btnSend").button();
```

but when loaded, this button doesn't have the style or functionality of the implemented script. And I haven't realized why.

Comment: the code doesn't seem to be correct, try posting the full corrected code for more accurancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer.

Just tried this code

```
$("#btnLoadContent").button().click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"form1.php",
        success:function(data){
            $("#divcontent").empty().append(data);
            $("#btnSend").button();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function in jQuery.

Also, if the ajax loaded content is within an iframe, the styles need to be called from within the loaded site again.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `.button()` will have already been executed when index.php loads. It will not execute again after form1.php has loaded. The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function has a callback parameter which will execute after the content has loaded. You should add the `$("#btnSend").button()` to that callback function instead.

For example:

```
$("#divcontent").empty().load('form1.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
    $("#btnSend").button();
});
```